# How migrate to specific schema of database PostgreSQL working with Symfony and Doctrine?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I did a migration after of created my database structure using `make:entity` command :

> $ symfony console make:migration

Now, I want to migrate to a specific schema into my `PostgresSQL` database.

[In the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) of Symfony says:

MANUAL TABLES. It is a common use case, that in addition to your generated database structure based on your doctrine entities you might need custom tables. By default, such tables will be removed by the `doctrine:migrations:diff` command. If you follow a specific scheme you can configure doctrine/dbal to ignore those tables. Let’s say all custom tables will be prefixed by t_. In this case, you just have to add the following configuration option to your doctrine configuration:

```
doctrine: dbal: schema_filter: ~^(?!t_)~
```

I understand that `schema_filter` is a filter applied to table names (only tables?) through a regular expression. Well, but `schema_filter` no reference the schemas created into a `PostgreSQL` database.

Then how can I migrate to a specific schema into a database?

When I execute the command:

> $ symfony console make:migration

it creates a migration file that contains a class with the functions 'up' and 'down', both with a parameter `$schema`. Here a fragment:

```
 public function up(Schema $schema) : void
 {
     // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
     $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

     $this->addSql('CREATE SEQUENCE division_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1');
```

This parameter can't assign a value when it is declared. Must be null.

Is it possible to use it to migrate to a specific schema?

Well, while I find a way, I did it like this:

public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
// this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
$this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on 'postgresql'.');

```
     $this->addSql('CREATE SEQUENCE my_schema_name.division_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1');
```

I mean that I write the schema name in all migration code generate by the command.

But I still believe that is possible to do it in another way. If yes then how?

I forgot it. Migration fails when I try with this line before of first sentence:

```
 $this->addSql('SET search_path TO my_schema_name');
```

Also I try assigning the schema name to the parameter $schema:

```
 $schema = 'my_schema_name'
```

It didn't work either.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#table apparently postgres semantics are different... if you specify the table with schema at the entity level, that hopefully sets the correct schemas in auto-generated migrations ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, thank you. I read this:

> the schema should be set via the db connection dsn, all tables by default end up in that schema.

Then I try set the connection parameters in `doctrine.yaml`: `url`, `dbname`, and `connectstring`, using this notation: `dbname.schema`, even: `dbname/schema`, but it does not work.

Then, a spite of this:

> you shouldn't hard-code schema names into migrations.

In the migration file was need set the schema for the connection:

```
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'postgresql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'postgresql\'.');

    $this->connection->exec('SET search_path TO my_schema_name;');

    $this->addSql('CREATE SEQUENCE division_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1');
    ...
```

However the table `migration_versions` did not exists in the schema, so I had to create it.

Comment: these code should go in down() method or up() method? when I created the same it went into down() method.

Comment: Manually, into both.